# Can I prevent fork() from returning to shell?

Tags: c, makefile, fork

I have a Makefile that looks something like this:

```
sometarget: 
    command_one    # calls fork()
    command_two
```

Here's the problem I'm running into when I do `make sometarget`:

1. `command_one` starts and eventually calls `fork()`.
2. The child process `exec`s something and finishes early, returning control to `make` before all the processing of `command_one` is done.
3. `command_two` then executes before the parent completes, causing the sequence to fail (as it depends on `command_one` finishing completely).

I can change `command_one` (the fork() and exec() have to stay, though), and I'd rather not change the Makefile if possible. Is there a way to prevent the child process from returning (on Linux)? I'm thinking the answer is no, but I've been wrong before...

Comment: A child process exiting should not cause the parent process to exit as well. You better show us some code so we can better help you.

Comment: Sorry, you're right, I should have included some actual code. I'll update the question.

Comment: Whoops, 'waitpid' (below) is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like your `command_one` looks something like this pseudo-code:

```
main() {
    pid_t child = fork();    /* ignore error for sake of example */
    if (child) {
        /* some work in the parent */
        exit;
    } else {
        /* some work in the child */
    }
    exit;
}
```

If you insert a `waitpid(2)` or `wait(2)` (or any member of the family) immediately before the *parent's* `exit`, it'll make sure both child and parent are finished before `make(1)` moves onto the next command. It'll look something more like this:

```
main() {
    pid_t child = fork();    /* ignore error for sake of example */
    if (child) {
        /* some work in the parent */
        exit;
    } else {
        /* some work in the child */
    }
    waitpid(child, &status, 0);  /* NEW LINE */
    exit(&status);
}
```

Comment: Might want to exit with the child's status as well.

Comment: 'waitpid' was what I was looking for and had somehow missed in reading manpages. Thanks!

Comment: @kerrek, thanks; it's a fine line between getting the pseudo-code too involved to be simple and just getting things wrong. This is easy enough to get right. Thanks!

Comment: @Ignacio: Good suggestion. It might need to be a bit more complicated, but at least mentioning it is explicit that _something_ needs to be done. Thanks!